# Pattern matching in Python regexp

Tags: python, html, regex

How can I use regexp in python to extract the date from an html `<div>` tags.
Html is something like this

`<div><strong>Date:<\/strong> Monday April 6, 2015 at 4:41PM <div>`

I need to get date in "yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm" format. Output for this should be "2015-04-06 16:41"

Comment: Can you show `yyyyddmmhhmm` with your example?

Comment: Use `DOM` and `XPath` to extract data from html. the lxml extension can do that for example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of approaching the problem with regular expressions (see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)), I would use an *HTML Parser*, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), and [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) for extracting the date. After extracting the date, use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to dump it into a string in the desired format:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from dateutil import parse
>>> s = "<div><strong>Date:</strong> Monday April 6, 2015 at 4:41PM <div>"
>>> text = soup.find('div').text
>>> parse(text, fuzzy=True).strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")
'2015-06-04 16:41'
```

Comment: Isn't `lxml` more suitable for real world use cases?

Comment: @hek2mgl it is opinion-based I'd say. There are different packages for the same task. Though I haven't seen a library so easy-to-use and natural as `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: (I'm new to Python) Isn't access to elements through XPath more straightforward and maintainable if the HTML changes than stepping through each node until the target? I mean Beatifulsoup can use lxml as the low level parser but does not support xpath. I can't get why.

Comment: @hek2mgl well, these are just different mechanism to accomplish similar goals. E.g. what would be more readable for you: `//td[@class="test"]/following-sibling::div`, or `soup.find('td', class_='test').find_next_sibling('div')`? Plus, `BeautifulSoup` supports CSS selectors which you can see as an alternative to XPath to locate elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with RegEx alone as you can't match the month when it is not in the source.